# Semisimple subalgebras of $M_4(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, semi-simple-rings

I'm working on the following problem and I'd like some guidance.

> Describe up to isomorphism all semisimple $\mathbb{C}$-subalgebras of $M_4(\mathbb{C})$ (4 by 4 matrices over $\mathbb{C}$).  Note that if $A$ and $B$ are $\mathbb{C}$-algebras and if $\alpha\in A$, and $\beta \in B$, have minimal polynomials $f,g$ respectively, then $(\alpha,\beta)\in A\oplus B$ has minimal polynomial $h = lcm(f,g)$

My thoughts are that by artin-wedderburn, this ring is simple because it's just a matrix ring, so shouldn't there should be no semi-simple subalgebras? but the hint seems to suggest that there are subalgebras.

[Source: Fall 1992](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Pre_2012_papers/Algebra_Pre_2011.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Wedderburn, any finite-dimensional semisimple algebra over $\mathbb C$ is of the form $$\tag1\bigoplus_{j=1}^m M_{n_j}(\mathbb C).$$
The question is how to fit this inside size $4\times 4$. In $(1)$ we would have $n_1+\cdots+n_m\leq 4$. So there are not that many choices: note that order is irrelevant, since isomorphism will not "see" the order of the blocks. So we may as well order the block sizes from bigger to smaller. Thus

- $n_1=4$.
- $n_1=3$, $n_2=1$
- $n_1=2$, $n_2=2$
- $n_1=2$, $n_2=1$, $n_3=1$
- $n_1=n_2=n_3=n_4=1$
- $n_1=3$
- $n_1=2$, $n_2=1$
- $n_1=n_2=n_3=1$
- $n_1=n_2=1$
- $n_1=1$

Comment: Could you explain why it needs to sum to 4 exactly?  What if we had something less than 4 by just letting some of the diagonal entries be 1?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't. I'm used to think about unital subalgebras. I'll edit right away.

Comment: Also, how do we show that it's not greater than 4? I believe it intuitively because it seems we're putting blocks along the diagonal, but I'm not sure how to go about showing that those are the only possibilites

Comment: It's not about the diagonal, although that's the intuition. It's about dimension. You have $M_4(\mathbb C)$ with dimension 16, so subalgebras will have dimensions from 1 to 15. But the dimensions, because of Wedderburn, are of the form $n_1^2+\cdots+n_m^2$. So it's about counting the sums of squares that add to 16 or less.

Comment: so for example, what would be wrong with having $n_1=\cdots=n_5 = 1$ because that would still give us dimension less than 16, but we have more than 4 as the sum.

Comment: If I understand Wedderburn's Theorem correctly, the direct sum is as algebras. In $\mathbb C^5$ you have five "pairwise orthogonal" idempotents, something that's impossible in $M_4(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81259/discussion-between-iyoa-and-martin-argerami).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat.  It's an awful feature of this site.

Comment: Fair enough.  What I didn't understand was what would the orthogonal idempotents look like? Just the standard basis vectors? I'm still not seeing how the sum needs to be less than or equal to 4. For example, what if now we had $n_1 = ...= n_4 = 2$. The sum would be 8 but the sum of squares would still be less than or equal to 16. And it seems like the hint they gave isn't really relevant?

Comment: Yes, if you take the standard basis in $\mathbb C^5$, you produce five pairwise orthogonal projections; that cannot exist in $M_4(\mathbb C)$. As for your second example, the sum of the **squares** has to be less than 16. If you have $n_1=n_2=n_3=n_4$, you would have four pairwise orthogonal copies of $M_2(\mathbb C)$, and you would be able to produce 8 pairwise orthogonal projections.

Comment: Oh okay, I think that makes sense. and last question, I thought that $M_4\mathbb{C}$ was simple as a $\mathbb{C}$-module, so how is it that there are so many subalgebras? I think I have some misconception on simplicity.

Comment: Simplicity is about ideals, not subalgebras. The property that $M_n(\mathbb C)$ has is that it lacks proper two sided ideals, that's why it's simple. You will (almost) always  have many subalgebras, starting with the subalgebra generated by each element.